# Firebase connection on error InsertFragment

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

the InsertFragment is red colour on my Android Studio.I am trying to connect with firebase.[image]

The code is this :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
public static FirebaseFirestore db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.sport).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SportActivity.class));
            }
        });
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)!=null){
            if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                return;
            }
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,new InsertFragment()).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix it?I did a project on firestore. I have create my tables there.On my Android studio I go to Firebase(from Menu I chose the Firebase) and then I tried the firestore cloud

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? It is not specified in the post and it's hard to find a root cause for any issue without knowing the issue itself.

Comment: A red flag seems a compilation error, and the error is, most of the time, pretty explicit. The error is related tto your code and not to Firebase. What does the error say?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @AlexMamo